# What does it mean by "the resulting behavior doesn't produce the consequence"?

Tags: conditioning

A lecture slide says:

> classical conditioning causes a stimulus to signal a positive or negative consequence; **the resulting behavior doesn't produce the consequence**.

What does it mean by the bolded sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slide is contrasting classical conditioning with operant conditioning.

In operant conditioning, you train that a *behavior* is paired with a reward or punishment. For example, a lever press dispensing a food pellet.

In classical conditioning, there is no relevant behavior. Some stimulus (rather than behavior) is paired with an outcome. For example, if there is a tone played before a shock, the tone will cause rodents to freeze in anticipation of the shock, but nothing about their freezing behavior is causing the shock.